# How to trigger the rebuild of a Makefile prerequisite file ONLY when a specific target is called?

Tags: makefile

I haven't found an answer so far, so I think this is not a repeat question.

I have some Makefile along the lines of:

```
include prerequisite_2

all: prerequisite_1 prerequisite_2

clean:
    rm *.mod

prerequisite_1:
    mkdir somedir

prerequisite_2:
    re-write existing file
```

The issue is that I want the prerequisite_2 to rebuild whenever the default goal is called (all) or when prerequisite_2 is called from the command line, and I know I can use `touch prerequisite_2`, `FORCE` or `.PHONY` to achieve this. However, I DO NOT want it to run every time (the written file contains dependency information for the Fortran files involved) as it doesn't make sense to also rebuild this when calling: `make clean`

Is it possible to emulate the effects of `FORCE` or `.PHONY` only when the depending targets are called?

Answer (score 0):

You can see what the goal targets are by looking at the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable.

So you can do something like:

```
ifeq (,$(if $(MAKECMDGOALS),$(filter-out all prerequisite-2,$(MAKECMDGOALS))))
include prerequisite-2
endif
```

The if condition will be true if `MAKECMDGOALS` is the empty string, or if it contains only `all` and/or `prerequisite-2` but not if it contains any other target.

Usually, this is not what you want though.  Usually you want to disable the include only if certain targets (`clean` is the classic example) are used.

This exact situation is even discussed in the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, while the conditional include is useful and will be included, it does not help me towards solving the actual problem stated. 

I have found that modifying the 'all' rule to touch a prerequisite of 'prerequisite_2'. This results in a somewhat imperfect and buggy solve, where 'prerequisite_2' is still run sometimes when something like `make clean` is prompted, if its dependency is out-of-date.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you want to do.  But, if you want the recipe to be considered `.PHONY` only in certain circumstances then just put the `.PHONY` into the conditional above.